# Synchronous decade counter only 3 AND gates

Tags: counter, synchronous

I need a design for a synchronous decade counter that can have no more than 3 gates, excluding the JK's. I do not need to design this myself as it is considered above the level of course I am doing, I am tasked with finding one and putting it into Multisim, but I can't find one. Can anyone help me out? P.S I know one exists as my tutor has one, but we are not allowed to use it.

Comment: 10 seconds of research http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/counter/count_3.html

Comment: That isn't right, for one it isn't a decade counter, and the decade counter they have has 5 additional gates.

Comment: Took me about 45 seconds to find one- and in Multisim (2 two-input and one three-input AND gates). Do you really expect others to use Google for you?

Comment: Honestly (believe me or not) my entire class hasn't been able to find one, and neither have I. I have spent considerable time googling it, do you really think I would have asked a question if I didn't think I had another choice, maybe I just didn't know how to look properly? I know there is one on the interwebs, a classmate of mine uploaded the tutors one onto a random website so he could say that was his source, but I can't find that. I honestly wouldn't have asked if I didn't think it was necessary, and I'm not trying to seem like I'm taking advantage, I honestly can't find one :(

Comment: I'd suggest editing your question, keeping it simple and highlighting what you found/tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXkomy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

To do a synchronous decade counter with 3 ANDs is quite tricky.  It did take me a while and this is my second attempt, but I must admit I am a bit rusty.  It does work.

To be perfectly honest, it really was not a fair question for your instructor to ask.  It's not a common solution because you are using three as T flip-flops and the last as a JK flip-flop.  So it's a bit of a kludge.  So you won't find it on the web (Well now you will).